# Excel Macros 2013: Is it possible to create a Macro that, with the shortcut key, formats an input value between Whole int and 2 decimal places

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I am attempting to create an Excel spreadsheet which holds information of students data, currently I have rounded all data to the nearest whole int.

What I wish to know is whether there is a way to use the Macro tool to toggle between to formats, using the same shortcut keys.

All suggestions and input are welcome and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your title and tags are confused. Is it Excel 2010 or 2013?

Comment: Thank you. I changed the tags for any future users in my predicament.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code snippet to do that, assuming you want to modify the currently selected cell:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
On Error Resume Next 'In case "Selection" is something that doesn't have a NumberFormat property
If Selection.NumberFormat = "0" Then Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00" Else: Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

End Sub
```

Comment: With this, you can also work a range of several cells at the same time, even if some of them will error.

Comment: Additional query: is it possible to use this code to create a similar Macro for text colour?

Comment: @josh yeah, you'll just need to reference the correct attributes `selection.font.color = vbblack` for instance

Comment: And again. Thank you "Raystafarian", you have been very helpful.